# Why observable Service is creating second Instance if called in the AppMdoule?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services

I created this Service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeaderService {
private _loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public isLoggedIn() {
    return this._loggedIn.asObservable();
  }
 public setLoggedIn(loggedIn: boolean) {
    this._loggedIn.next(loggedIn);
  }
}
```

I have 2 Modules in my Angular App. The Main One and another. When I call `setLoggedIn` from a Component which is part of `ÀppModule` it is not using the same Service Instance as the One from the `HeaderComponent` where I subscribed to the Observable via `isLoggedIn()`, but when I call the update Method in a Component which is not Part of `ÀppModule` the one which the Subscription is called. 
As I read on Angular Website when declaring a Service with my Syntax it should be a Singleton so I'm confused now. Anyone had a similar Issue? And successful fixed it.

My `HeaderComponent` inside of `AppModule`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public sites; //Array of Routes displayed in Navigation
  constructor(private headerService: HeaderService, ) {
    ...
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headerService.isLoggedIn().subscribe(((isLoggedIn) => {
      if (isLoggedIn)
        this.sites = this.headerService.loginLinks;
      else
        this.sites = this.headerService.logoutLinks;
    }));
  }
}
```

My `RegisterComponent`in the `LoginScreenModule`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register1',
  templateUrl: './register1.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './register1.component.css',
    './../../assets/stylesheets/multiple-use/form.css'
  ]
})
export class Register1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private headerService: HeaderService

  ) {
    ...
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headerService.setLoggedIn(false);
  }
}
```

My `SearchComponent`in `AppModule`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private headerService: HeaderService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.headerService.setLoggedIn(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your modules and components

Comment: remove all `provide: [ HeaderService ]` from every module except for `AppModule` and that way you'll have a singleton.

Comment: I don't get what you are talking about. I should add the ```HeaderService``` only to ``` ÀppModule``` in  ```providers:[]```

Comment: @KurtHamilton I will provide the Components that use the Service, is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @Willey3x37 What I really meant was - If you search your whole project for "HeaderService" - what results do you get. So yes, every component where it's used, and anywhere else. Also, your proof that different instances are being used. A stackblitz would be great.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I searched my Project and these are the only Classes the Service is used, but sure a Stackblitz would be more interactive and I´ll try to create one now (which I didn't do before)

Comment: @Willey3x37 Thanks. There's no rational reason for the behaviour you are seeing based on the code, so recreating will either help you or someone else find the mistake.

Comment: @KurtHamilton Yeah I know but I added a log message to Comstructor of ```HeaderService```and the Message occurs two times.

Comment: @Willey3x37 I definitely want to see this in action now...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209954/discussion-between-willey3x37-and-kurt-hamilton).

Comment: @KurtHamilton I tried to reproduce but I couldn't doesn't have the Error in Stackblitz Repo :( So frustrating
I can try to provide you the whole codebase it is not very much yet Login Screens and Search. Is it ok for you?

Comment: @Willey3x37 Strange. I'm not quite interested enough to take a look at your source code!

Comment: @KurtHamilton Ok maybe I find it out myself thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the injection from service class, you are also injecting it via @Injectable decorator.

Please remove it from this line in your service class.  `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`.

It should look like below statement

```
@Injectable()
```